# Moving a range-based iterator forward from within the loop

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, for-loop, vector

I'm iterating over a multidimensional `vector<vector<float> >` using a range-based `for` loop. So, something like this:

```
for(vector<float> &row : myVector){

    // Do some stuff

}
```

I'd like to be able to move forward some fixed number `n` rows based on conditionals within the loop. I could, of course, do something like:

```
for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < rows && j < columns; ++i, ++j){
   // Do some stuff
}
```

However, using a range-based loop is so advantageous for the algorithm contained within the loop that I'd much prefer keeping it, if possible. Is this possible and, if so, how?

Comment: why is it so advantageous? It doesnt do anything that you cannot do with iterators

Comment: range based for loops print the entire range.  You'll either need a different kind of loop, or a range adapter.

Comment: Also, store your data in single dimension vector, which has much better cache performance and will show real speedups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some context missing, so I'll just blindy trust what you write: You know how to do your special increment with an iterator based loop along the line of:

```
for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < rows && j < columns; ++i, ++j){
   // Do stuff
}
```

But also you have a range based loop:

```
for(vector<float> &row : myVector){

    // Do some stuff
}
```

And you don't want to change `// Do some stuff`.

The thing is, range based loops aren't magic. For each range based loop there is a completely equivalent traditional loop. Range based loops iterating from being till and and **not** granting you access to indices or iterators is what makes them so attractive. If you do need indices then use something else.

Your same `// Do some stuff` can be used unchanged in a iterator based loop:

```
for(auto it = myVector.begin(); it != myVector.end(); ++it) {
   auto& row = *it;

   // Do some stuff

   // Do your special increment stuff with it
}
```

Note that this `// Do some stuff` can be exactly the same as in the above range based for loop.

For more details on how range based for loops can be written as loops with iterators I refer you to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).

Answer (score 0):

Try boost::range or std::ranges. This is how code with boost::range will probably look like.

```cpp
auto nRows = myVector | boost::adaptors::sliced(0, rows);
for(auto& row : nRows)
{
    auto nVals = row | boost::adaptors::sliced(0, cols);
    for(auto& val : nVals)
    {
    }
}
```